# Changing display format of Double number after performing calculations

Tags: android, string, decimal, android-edittext, number-formatting

I perform calculations using a double as follows:

```
int minutes;
double seconds;
double DecMinutes;


// Handle Dd in; DMS, and DMm out
Calculate myCalculate = new Calculate(inDecimal); {
double outMinutes = myCalculate.getMinute();
double outSeconds = myCalculate.getSecond();
double outDecMinute = myCalculate.getDecMinute();


minutes = (int) outMinutes;
seconds = outSeconds;
DecMinutes = outDecMinute;


} // end myCalculate

// Convert result back to String
c = Integer.toString(minutes);
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDMSLatMin)).setText(c);
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDMmLatMin)).setText(c);
c = Double.toString(seconds);
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDMSLatSec)).setText(c);
c = Double.toString(DecMinutes);
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDMmLatDecMin)).setText(c);
```

My main concern is with the double DecMinutes output.  Because it's a Decimal-Minutes calculation I need to use double.  My layout already displays the decimal point as a fixed character so instead of displaying 0.0734 I want to display 0734 in the EditText box txtDMmLatDecMin.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, please remember to accept answers as correct if you were able to solve your problem using that answer. Would appreciate it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you want to drop the zero and the decimal point?

Maybe there is an easier way, but at the top of my head I am thinking you can use [`String.split()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).  With the downside that you have to create a new String array to hold the values.

So after you do this:

```
c = Double.toString(DecMinutes);
String[] strSplit = c.split("\\.");
```

Then you can do:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDMmLatDecMin)).setText(strSplit[1]);
```

Again, maybe there is an easier way. :)

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you...I did have to use String[] strSplit = c.split("\\."); Since the period is reserved regex.